# How to disable globalisation?

Tags: episerver-7

How to disable globalization (I mean that I need just one language) so that I don't get this kind of links: 
`/en/...&epslanguage=en`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Globalization can be disabled in Admin mode under system settings, or you can disable it in **episerver.config** by setting **uiShowGlobalizationUserInterface="false"** on your **SiteSettings** element.

If you just want to get rid of the language branch "/en/" in the URL you can set the default language in **EPiServerFramework.config**:

```
  <siteHostMapping>
    <siteHosts siteId="YourSiteName">
      <add name="*" language="en" />
    </siteHosts>
  </siteHostMapping>
```

**Edit:** Since CMS 7.5 the host language settings are configured in admin mode and are stored in the database instead of in the config file.